# How to scroll in selenium (python) when only 1 part of the webpage is scrollable

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to be able to scroll down to the bottom of a page. Reason for this is my Xpath elements are not visible until they have been scrolled to(if that makes sense). So, to be able to interact with all elements i want to scroll down to the bottom

However, only a small part of the page is scrollable (the reviews) instead of the entire page.
My code for opening the page is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import csv
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile Safari/535.19" }

options = EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
options.use_chromium = True
driver = Edge(options=options)

# navigate to login screen
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps/place/AT5/@52.3556437,4.8470182,14z/data=!4m10!1m2!2m1!1sat5!3m6!1s0x47c60995371e3933:0x50f58efcb7962ea8!8m2!3d52.3462526!4d4.8306237!9m1!1b1')
#driver.maximize_window()
driver.set_window_size(250, 1080)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[20]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/span[2]/button').click()
```

I have tried multiple solutions, but none of them seemed to work.

I have tried

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

and

```
while driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div'):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    Divs=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[11]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[43]/div[2]/div') ### This is the last element i want to interact with
    if 'End of Results' in Divs:
        print 'end'
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Nothing i have tried worked.
Does anybody know how i can either

- scroll down to the bottom of the page

or

- be able to interact with the last element without it being visible at the beginning?

Comment: There no element to scroll in the google map other than reviews , could you add more details or screen shot on what lement to scrool to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    
url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/AT5/@52.3556437,4.8470182,14z/data=!4m10!1m2!2m1!1sat5!3m6!1s0x47c60995371e3933:0x50f58efcb7962ea8!8m2!3d52.3462526!4d4.8306237!9m1!1b1'

browser.get(url)
scroll = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show"]')))
browser.execute_script(
    "arguments[0].scrollBy(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight)", scroll)
```

use the above code to scroll through review, you have to do scroll on the scroll bar css locator which is

```
[class="section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show"]
```

Comment: this does not seem to work.
I get a Javascript error. "Message: javascript error: $ is not defined"
Does this code work in python or is there another code i should use in python?

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld updated the answer , use the updated one jquery should be available in <script> to use $

Comment: unfortunately i still get an error. This time I get a NoSuchElementExpectation for "scroll"

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld added wait s now try

Comment: It still show an error unfortunately, this time it shows "__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given"

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld added full code please try

Comment: I now get a time out error. So no luck unfortunately. I do really appreciate the effort btw

Comment: i just tested the code it works fine cou;ld you just use that 4 lines

Comment: It still doesnt work. Could it be this is because i'm using Edge instead of google Chrome?

Comment: could you try google chromeand see if it works

Comment: That seems to do the trick. However it only scrolls for a certain amount, how can i make it so that it scrolls to the end (i could make a for loop and let it run multiple times, but this seems inefficient) ?

Comment: @Raymondvanzonneveld thats the only way as trhr reviews are loaded only after scrolling down

Comment: its called lazy loading